# Need help plot matrix binary python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Ask for help in like python.
I have a pandas where the rows are the "people" and the columns are the subjects. When it has the value "1", it means that there is a relationship between the two and "zero" for no. That simple.
As well as plotting a binary matrix between this relationship, and the people and x the subjects.
The question is that I can't even make this plot "smaller" according to the photo of the objective. I always come across the "trace".

Example code:

```
matrixNumpy = matrix.to_numpy()
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
fig.add_subplot(2, 4, 1)
plt.imshow(matrixNumpy, aspect='auto', interpolation='none', cmap='Greys')
```

[Pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5hSX.png)

[Objetive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j8OZ.png)

[how is it currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLE8I.png)

---

New photos

G = Graph Bipartite

[create matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC3JD.png)
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obwuD.png)

```
matrix = bipartite.biadjacency_matrix(G, Hash, assunto).todense()
matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=Hash, columns=assunto)
matrix = matrix.squeeze()
matrix

matrixNumpy = matrix.to_numpy()
matrixNumpy.shape

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(15,15))
ax = axes[0]
ax.imshow(matrixNumpy, aspect='auto', cmap='Greys', )
ax = axes[1]
ax.imshow(total_sort_mat(matrixNumpy), aspect='auto', cmap='Greys',)
```

TY

Comment: Have you tried changing `aspect='equal'`?

Comment: with this information it doesn't work, the plot comes out empty

Comment: If share a toy example instead of the screenshots, I will be able to help you better.

Comment: The words "pandas", "Objective" and "how is it currently". They are linked to the photo, did you see it?

If I put "equal" the plot comes out "empty", with no information.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to copy the data from a screenshot, so there is my attempt to help you out.

Considering that you are using a 2D numpy at the end, let's go with a toy example

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mat = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(45,), p=[1./3, 2./3]).reshape((3,15))
```

If we plot this using `aspect='auto'`, we get a result which is similar to what you don't want

```
plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
plt.imshow(mat, aspect='auto', interpolation='none', cmap='Greys')
```

[image]

If you use `aspect='equal'`, it returns

```
plt.imshow(mat, aspect='equal', interpolation='none', cmap='Greys')
```

[image]

The other possible reasons why it is not working might be

- Since mentioned in your comment that you are getting an empty plot when `aspect='auto'`, change your `figsize=(15,15)` to a smaller value like such as `figsize=(1,1)`
- Even after changing the `figsize` if you are getting empty plot, then the matrix may be too large to be rendered. Try plotting a small portion first.
- If you are in a Jupyter notebook, check if some of the previously executed cells are not affecting your variables.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those points. The matrix is really big, there can be 200 columns

Comment: I put new information ty

Comment: the same occurs with the example of the question here, whether a lot of information or not

Comment: If the above-given example didn't work for you. I will focus on the last point of the possible reason. I ran it using the matplotlib 3.6.0 and NumPy 1.23.3 versions.

Comment: I'm using matplotlib 3.1.1 and numpy 1.17.1